# Installing pip: python

Tags: python, pip

My problem is that pip is not installing on Windows. I have downloaded pip.py.
Although, type pip in cmd I get:

NameError: name 'pip' is not defined.

Help please.

Comment: ...try downloading [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) and running that?

Comment: there should be something know as `get-pip.py` download it and `type python get-pip.py` then pip will be available this is in python 2.x

Comment: Yes, I have already downloaded get-pip.py and ran python get-pip.py, and I get 'Ivalid Syntax'

Comment: @Jengo provided what you have done in your question and give what error you got

Comment: Don't try to do these things at the Python prompt.  Do them at the command line.

Comment: @VigneshKalai I did provide what I did?

Comment: @Kevin Same errors with command line.

Comment: did you `type python get-pip.py` in the command prompt in the same dir as the file is

Comment: @Jengo: No command line in the world gives "NameError" and "SyntaxError"; those are exclusively Python errors.  You are typing this at the Python prompt.

Comment: You haven't set the python path in the environment variable, set it and calling `pip` should go fine, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2425215) should help

Comment: @KDawG Thanks, is this right? C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath/C:\Python27\Scripts

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes, I did. Same error.

Comment: just type `python` in cmd prompt and what do you get

Comment: @VigneshKalai Python is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: that means python is not set in your path.try setting python to your path and try installing pip

Comment: @VigneshKalai This is my current path : C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath/C:\Python27\Scripts

Comment: @Jengo in which folder is python installed

Comment: if it is in c it should look something like `C:\Python `

Comment: you could set it to path like this `path %path%;C:\Python `

Comment: Bad pathsep.  Should be ;  not /

Comment: Python is in C drive. So should my path be like this:

Comment: @VigneshKalai C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath/path %path%;C:\Python

Comment: @Jengo why are you adding it to java path .for more on setting path se [this](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set up the environment variable - it means that you need to be in the folder of pip.

So, if you installed pip in c:\pip. you need to browse to c:\pip to run pip.

Does it make sense?